# Image won't load completely on Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an Image element in my WP7.5 Silverlight app for which I tried changing its source both in XAML and programmatically. Whatever I try, I cannot load big images(in size or in bytes, I don't know) completely.

Here is my code:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem>
  <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="2, 4, 0, 0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <StackPanel x:name="stackPanel">
      <TextBlock x:Name="debugger" Foreground="Black"/>
      <Image Source="http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/1574819_460s.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" ImageOpened="Image_ImageOpened"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</controls:PanoramaItem>


private void Image_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    debugger.Text = "DONE";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Limited Image Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Images) on MSDN.

> Due to the limited screen resolution of Windows Phone, another way to optimize performance is to limit the image size to 2000 x 2000 pixels, which is the size limit of images in the Windows Phone environment. Larger images will be sampled at a lower resolution. Also, if you use images that are larger than 2000 x 2000 pixels, they will be significantly slower to appear.
>
> If you must use images larger than 2000 x 2000 you should only display a portion of the file that meets the 2000 limit. You can do this by loading the image into a `WriteableBitmap` and using the `LoadJpeg(WriteableBitmap, Stream)` extension method.