# Windows Phone 7.1: Split byte[] image and convert to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Edit: To those who need to blit an image(i.e. copy a part of a WriteableBitmap to another), you can use Buffer.BlockCopy and use WriteableBitmaps' Pixels int[] arrays as argument.

I asked this question before: [Image won't load completely on Windows Phone 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754527/image-wont-load-completely-on-windows-phone-7-5)

I've been working on this issue for several hours now and I've tried several things. I'm not familiar with image types etc. so it's possible that I'm missing a basic theory (like I cannot split a byte[] image and convert them into BitmapImage).

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Download an image(JPEG) from Web using WebClient.
2. Decode the JPEG from the stream that WebClient returned to me using PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg and get a WriteableBitmap object
3. Convert WriteableBitmap.Pixels array from int[] to byte[]
4. Split the byte[] array into several pieces, so they won't exceed 2000x2000 size limit
5. Convert each piece to BitmapImage so I can use them in my WP7.1 Silverlight app.

But I get an System.Exception with Unspecified error in System.Windows.dll in those lines:

```
 firstImg.SetSource(ms);

 newImg.SetSource(ms2);
```

BTW, the jpeg I'm downloading is a valid jpeg, I can display it without trying to split it.

Edit: Jpeg that I download is smaller than 2000 in width and bigger than 2000 in height.

Here's my code:

```
private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteableBitmap rawImg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.Result);
        byte[] arr;
        int height = rawImg.PixelHeight;
        int count = 0;

        if (height < 2000)
            images.Add(new MyImage(rawImg));
        else
        {
            arr = ConvertToByte(rawImg);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(arr, 0, 4 * rawImg.PixelWidth * 2000);
            count++;
            BitmapImage firstImg = new BitmapImage();
            firstImg.SetSource(ms);
            images.Add(new MyImage(firstImg));

            while (height > 2000)
            {
                MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
                ms2.Write(arr, count*2000, 4 * rawImg.PixelWidth * Math.Min(arr.Length - count*2000, 2000));
                count++;
                height -= 2000;
                BitmapImage newImg = new BitmapImage();
                newImg.SetSource(ms2);
                images.Add(new MyImage(newImg));
            }
        }     
    }

private byte[] ConvertToByte(WriteableBitmap wb)
    {
        int w = wb.PixelWidth;
        int h = wb.PixelHeight;
        int[] p = wb.Pixels;
        int len = p.Length;
        byte[] result = new byte[4 * w * h];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j += 4)
        {
            int color = p[i];
            result[j + 0] = (byte)(color >> 24);
            result[j + 1] = (byte)(color >> 16);
            result[j + 2] = (byte)(color >> 8);
            result[j + 3] = (byte)(color);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you write to the `MemoryStream`, the position is advanced. Before setting the source, reset the position.

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

Edit - You could use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). It's a very fast library that can perform byte conversions to and from WriteableBitmaps. You could also create a new WriteableBitmap from copying sections of the bigger image by using the `blitting` feature.

Comment: I still get the same exception.

Comment: Could look into the WriteableBitmapEx library.

Comment: Thank you. WriteableBitmapEx can copy pixels from one WriteableBitmap to another. Exactly fit for my needs.